# Spinner doesn't show and then everything updates once the task in the spinner completes

Tags: python, streamlit

I am creating a chat app using Streamlit that will be connected to an LLM to respond to the user.

While the LLM is generating a response, I would like a spinner to show until the response can be printed.

Currently, I am mocking the LLM's response generation with a simple `time.sleep(5)`. However, the spinner doesn't show for these 5 seconds, and then the UI updates with the response.

The Streamlit app:

```py
import streamlit as st

from sensei.ui import text, utils

st.chat_input("Your response...", key="disabled_chat_input", disabled=True)

if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["messages"] = [
        {"name": "Sensei", "avatar": "", "content": message, "translated": True, "printed": False}
        for message in text.ONBOARDING_START_MESSAGES[st.session_state.source_language]
    ]


for message in st.session_state.messages:
    with st.chat_message(name=message["name"], avatar=message["avatar"]):
        if message["name"] == "Sensei" and not message["printed"]:
            utils.stream_message(message=message["content"])
            message["printed"] = True
        else:
            st.markdown(body=message["content"])

if st.session_state.messages[-1]["name"] == "user":
    with st.spinner("Thinking..."):
        sensei_response = utils.temp_get_response()
        st.session_state.messages.append(
            {"name": "Sensei", "avatar": "", "content": sensei_response, "translated": True, "printed": False}
        )
        st.rerun()

if user_response := st.chat_input(placeholder="Your response...", key="enabled_chat_input"):
    st.session_state.messages.append({"name": "user", "avatar": "user", "content": user_response})
    st.rerun()
```

The `temp_get_response` function:

```py
def temp_get_response() -> str:
    """Get a response from the user."""
    time.sleep(5)
    return "Well isn't that just wonderful!"
```

The `stream_message` function (this isn't the issue as the behaviour is the same if I write normally without streaming):

```py
def stream_message(message: str) -> None:
    """Stream a message to the chat."""
    message_placeholder = st.empty()
    full_response = ""
    for chunk in message.split():
        full_response += chunk + " "
        time.sleep(0.1)
        message_placeholder.markdown(body=full_response + "▌")
    message_placeholder.markdown(body=full_response)
```

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved the issue simply by reordering the last 2 if statements and removing the `st.rerun()` calls. I'm really not too sure why this fixed it, but it did!

```py
import streamlit as st

from sensei.ui import text, utils

st.chat_input("Your response...", key="disabled_chat_input", disabled=True)

if "messages" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["messages"] = [
        {"name": "Sensei", "avatar": "", "content": message, "printed": False}
        for message in text.ONBOARDING_START_MESSAGES[st.session_state.source_language]
    ]

for message in st.session_state.messages:
    with st.chat_message(name=message["name"], avatar=message["avatar"]):
        if message["name"] == "Sensei" and not message["printed"]:
            utils.stream_message(message=message["content"])
            message["printed"] = True
        else:
            st.markdown(body=message["content"])

if user_response := st.chat_input(placeholder="Your response...", key="enabled_chat_input"):
    with st.chat_message(name="user", avatar="user"):
        st.markdown(body=user_response)
    st.session_state.messages.append({"name": "user", "avatar": "user", "content": user_response})


if st.session_state.messages[-1]["name"] == "user":
    with st.spinner("Thinking...", cache=True):
        sensei_response = utils.temp_get_response()
    with st.chat_message(name=message["name"], avatar=message["avatar"]):
        utils.stream_message(message=sensei_response)
    st.session_state.messages.append({"name": "Sensei", "avatar": "", "content": sensei_response, "printed": True})
```